# Best syntax for traversing menu paths in posts

Tags: discussion, markdown

Reviewing posts, there are many variations of traversing menu paths, such as:

> Tools->preferences
>
> Tools -> preferences
>
> Tools--->Preferences
>
> Tools >> Preferences
>
> Tools → Preferences

Per consistency, readability, or search engine optimization are there recommended best practices as to the syntax of menu paths in posts?

Comment: *See that Tools menu? Click it. Hold the mouse button down, don't hold it down, doesn't matter. See Preferences? Click it. No, not... - ok, see the Tools menu?*

Comment: Do we really need to worry about consistency in this case? Any of the options you list seem just fine. If there is anything unclear about what you see in a specific post, by all means try to improve it. But I don't think this needs all that much discussion. Whether SEO comes into play I don't know.

Comment: @Bart Agreed, but interested in syntactic sugar that pops long unwieldy action command sequences from text.  I think your comment answers my question.